# Find $\int 1/(1+\sin(x) \cos(x))\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate
$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sin(x) \cos(x)}dx$$

Now, I have the correct solution in my book, but I can't see where I go wrong.

Attempt:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Your last step, where you integrate $1/(k^2 \beta^2 + 1)$ with respect to $\beta$, isn't right… you shouldn't just get $\tan^{-1}(k\beta)$, but should get an additional factor of $1/k$.  (Here $k=2/\sqrt{3}$.)

Comment: Indeed: $\int \frac{d\beta}{(k\beta)^2+1}=\frac{1}{k}\int\frac{d(k\beta)}{(k\beta)^2+1}$

Comment: solved. thanks.